# Kendo Grid with Angular custom directives for cell editor templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

we have custom control types(directives) defined in our project, we are trying to render those directives in kendo editable when user want to edit a record and also when editing each cell for a record must be in two-way databinding and each cell should react with the modification of one cell
 eg: i have a continents dropdown based on the selection countries dropdown shoul d load related countries this should happen when editing of record also.

Related to the above scenario if anyone have any Implementation Kendo Grid+Angular js

I have a sample here, i am facing issues to render edit Cell templates.

`enter code here`[plnkrExample](http://plnkr.co/edit/ig8sCAL6FzP2EAL0kH4Q?p=preview)

Please help us 
Thanks In Advance.